# How to query WSO2 UDDI registry (of Governance registry) via UDDI webservice?

Tags: registry, wso2, uddi

Following the instructions [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance450/Support+for+UDDI) for how to query the UDDI registry of WSO2 Governance Registry. However, when I use the webservice 'find_service' or 'find_business' from the wsdl `https://localhost:9443/services/UDDIInquiryService?wsdl` I just get the UDDI services listed e.g.

> <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>      <soapenv:Body>
>         <serviceList xmlns="urn:uddi-org:api_v3" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns3="urn:uddi-org:custody_v3" xmlns:ns4="urn:uddi-org:policy_v3" xmlns:ns5="urn:uddi-org:repl_v3" xmlns:ns6="urn:uddi-org:sub_v3" xmlns:ns7="urn:uddi-org:subr_v3" xmlns:ns8="urn:uddi-org:vscache_v3" xmlns:ns9="urn:uddi-org:policy_v3_instanceParms" xmlns:ns10="urn:uddi-org:vs_v3">
>
> <listDescription>
>     <includeCount>7</includeCount>
>               <actualCount>7</actualCount>
>               <listHead>1</listHead>
>            </listDescription>
>            <serviceInfos>
>               <serviceInfo businessKey="uddi:juddi.apache.org:businesses-asf" serviceKey="uddi:juddi.apache.org:services-custodytransfer">
>                  <name xml:lang="en">UDDI Custody and Ownership Transfer Service</name>
>               </serviceInfo>
>               <serviceInfo businessKey="uddi:juddi.apache.org:businesses-asf" serviceKey="uddi:juddi.apache.org:services-inquiry">
>                  <name xml:lang="en">UDDI Inquiry Service</name>
>               </serviceInfo>
>               <serviceInfo businessKey="uddi:juddi.apache.org:businesses-asf" serviceKey="uddi:juddi.apache.org:services-publish">
>                  <name xml:lang="en">UDDI Publish Service</name>
>               </serviceInfo>
>               <serviceInfo businessKey="uddi:juddi.apache.org:businesses-asf" serviceKey="uddi:juddi.apache.org:services-security">
>                  <name xml:lang="en">UDDI Security Service</name>
>               </serviceInfo>
>               <serviceInfo businessKey="uddi:juddi.apache.org:businesses-asf" serviceKey="uddi:juddi.apache.org:services-subscriptionlistener">
>                  <name xml:lang="en">UDDI Subscription Listener Service</name>
>               </serviceInfo>
>               <serviceInfo businessKey="uddi:juddi.apache.org:businesses-asf" serviceKey="uddi:juddi.apache.org:services-subscription">
>                  <name xml:lang="en">UDDI Subscription Service</name>
>               </serviceInfo>
>               <serviceInfo businessKey="uddi:juddi.apache.org:businesses-asf" serviceKey="uddi:juddi.apache.org:services-publisher">
>                  <name xml:lang="en">jUDDI Publisher Service</name>
>               </serviceInfo>
>            </serviceInfos>
>         </serviceList>
>      </soapenv:Body>
>   </soapenv:Envelope>

I have added other services to greg but cannot find them through UDDI webservices.
What am I doing wrong - are there any other steps (such as providing authentication credentials) that I need to be doing that aren't included as part of the documentation?

This is insane! I have followed the documentation to the letter and get some results (as above) so it appears that something is working, just not receiving any details of services that I have added to the registry.

can anyone offer any advice here? I have searched and searched for any snippet to try but nothing.

UPDATE: tried this at home too, on Linux box and experience exactly the same behaviour.
So, tried on Windows (laptop with XP), Java6, GREG 4.5.3, and
Linux Ubuntu 13.04, Java7 (openJDK), GREG 4.5.3

Answer (score 0):

You have not adding the WSDL URL when adding the service, Thats why you not getting this working